# Getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'body')

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, supertest

I am new to JS and trying learn node - supertest. I have came across this error. Kindly guide me.

```
import { describe } from "mocha";
import supertest from "supertest";
import { expect } from "chai";

const request = supertest('https://gorest.co.in/public/v2/');

const api_token = '45faa1e4b06b3cc1d5ecfbe639235376838cf638c85f88cb9bcc04e954bbf77f';

describe('GET /user' , () =>{
it('fetching user details', (done) =>{
    request.get(`users?access-token=${api_token}`).end((err,res) =>{
       console.log(err);
        console.log(res.body);  
   
       done();

    })
})
})
```

Console Error Image for the reference:
[image]

Comment: You shouldn't try to use `res` if `err` is not `null`. When you get an error there's no result.

Comment: How can i print the response on the console then.

Comment: `if (res) { console.log(res.body); }`

Comment: Its still not printing. Though it has a response

Comment: GET /user
    ✔ fetching user details (884ms)


  1 passing (890ms)

Comment: @jessipinkman, it's seems that you fixed the issue, could you clarify for other users what you changed to achieve this?

Comment: It still not printing the response on console. But it passed the test. What i did is - `if (res) { console.log(res.body); }`